# Akka-Cluster: indirectly connected member does not receive UnreachableMember event about himself

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, gossip

There's something I'm trying to understand about failure detection and the gossip of the detection.

A multi-jvm test I wrote seems to show that a member that has been detected as failed but still reachable via other nodes will not receive an `UnreachableMember(self)` event, telling him that he has been detected as unreachable by some member.

The test went as follows: 
In a 3 node cluster, `node2` detects `node3` as unreachable, `node3` detects `node2` as unreachable. Then `node1` receives the information that `node2` and `node3` are unreachable (through gossiping). However, `node2` and `node3` never receive the fact that they were themselves detected as unreachable.

After some digging in the `GossipSpec` I found out that the "falsely" unreachable member will reach convergence even though it is noted as `Unreachable` (see the test `"not reach convergence when unreachable"`).

Is that the reason why I'm not seeing the `UnreachableMember(self)` event?

The ultimate goal I'm trying to get at is to detect that a member has been falsely found unreachable since it is unreachable from that given member due to a faulty channel between both.